# Connecting ssh client with Paramiko using Python to dell idrac fails keyboard-interactive authentication

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

So dell changed something in their new idrac firmware where they require a keyboard interactive authentication after you login and I can no longer login using Paramiko.

https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management-General/iDRAC8-2-70-70-70-SSH-keyboard-interactive-authentication/td-p/7427565

Someone posted a code snippet in the forums to patch Paramiko client.py I added the following to the connect function

```
if password is not None:
            try:
                self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
                return
                self._log(DEBUG, "trying password")
                allowed_types = self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
                if not allowed_types:
                    return
            except SSHException as e:
                saved_exception = e
elif two_factor:
            if 'keyboard-interactive' in allowed_types:
                try:
                    self._log(DEBUG, "trying interactive")
                    self._transport.auth_interactive_dumb(username)
                    return
                except SSHException as e:
                    saved_exception = e
```

but still got the same error. Here is the ssh connection function i'm using.

```
def connectSSH(my_file, user_name, password):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ip = str(my_file.split(',')[0]).strip()
    try:
        ssh.connect(ip, 22, user_name, password, look_for_keys=False)
        return ssh
    except:
        with open(f'{ip}.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.writelines(ip + '\t COULDN\'T CONNECT\n')
```

when I run it in idle it conects but says awaiting authentication

ssh.get_transport()
<paramiko.Transport at 0xe43670 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (connected; awaiting auth)>

here is the trace back I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('racadm getsysinfo')
  File "C:\Users\kevinc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 508, in exec_command
    chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\kevinc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 875, in open_session
    return self.open_channel(
  File "C:\Users\kevinc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1006, in open_channel
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\kevinc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2055, in run
    ptype, m = self.packetizer.read_message()
  File "C:\Users\kevinc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 459, in read_message
    header = self.read_all(self.__block_size_in, check_rekey=True)
  File "C:\Users\kevinc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 303, in read_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError
```

any help appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm I figured it out didn't know there was a method to send a fake entry to the connection no need to edit the client.py file

here is my method to connect if anyone needs it 
**edit
noticed that if its the old version and didn't need the further auth it would fail so i put in a check

```
def connectSSH(my_file, user_name, password):
    ip = str(my_file.split(',')[0]).strip()
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(ip, 22, user_name, password)
        key_auth = str(ssh.get_transport())
        if 'awaiting auth' in key_auth:
            (ssh.get_transport()).auth_interactive_dumb(user_name)
        return ssh
    except:
        with open(f'{ip}.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.writelines(ip + '\t COULDN\'T CONNECT\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: Python code using Paramiko that tried to log into a Dell iDRAC stopped working with simple username/password authentication.  I am running my Python/Paramiko --> iDRAC code against iDRAC Controller version 9 and found that keyboard-interactive authentication is now needed.

This code below, similar to the original poster's code, shows a working example of logging in to an iDRAC 9 controller using username/password authentication:

```
import paramiko
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('ssh_test_app')
logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

host = '10.255.1.2'
password = 'mypw'
username = 'myuser'
port = 22

client = paramiko.SSHClient()

client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

retval = 0

cmd = 'racadm getsysinfo'

try:
    client.connect(host, port=port, username=username, password=password, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
    transport = client.get_transport()

    if not transport.is_authenticated():
        transport.auth_interactive_dumb(username)

    if transport.is_authenticated():
        logger.info('transport is authenticated')
        _stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
        res = stdout.read()
        logger.info('Command {0}:\n{1}'.format(cmd, res))
    else:
        logger.error('transport is not authenticated')

except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    logger.error('paramiko.AuthenticationException')
    retval = 1

except paramiko.BadHostKeyException:
    logger.error('paramiko.BadHostKeyException')
    retval = 1

except paramiko.SSHException:
    logger.error('paramiko.SSHException')
    retval = 1

finally:
    transport.close()

logger.info('Exiting at end of script: exit code {0}'.format(retval))

exit(retval)
```